# Split Line with Two Delimiters

Tags: c#, string, winforms, list, split

**CONTEXT**

I'm designing an application that will bring in initial settings for an application to use.  The settings are imported through a text file and all are have this format:

```
Color= Blue
Size= 5
Value = 100
```

Each line is a created object Setting(string a, string b) using a delimiter of "=" with Line.Split().  Each object created is then added to a List(Setting) _settingsList.

**PROBLEM**

There are 2 settings at the very end of the text file that are in the format

```
Location = 123 This Street, City, State, Zip Code
```

In this situation, I want to split it by both "=" and "," and use that to create an object Location(string name, string address, string city, string state, string zip).  Finally, this would be added to a List _locList.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
string line;

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{  
   string[] words = line.Split('=');
   if(words[0].ToLower().Trim() == "Location")
   {
       string keepThis = words[0].ToLower().Trim();
       string[] Words = line.Split('='); //how to split by 2 delimiters?
       _locList.Add(new Location(Words[0], Words[1], Words[2], words[3], Words[4]);
   }
  _settingsList.Add(new Setting(words[0], words[1]));
}
```

the string keepThis is there because I tried to remove the entire "Location = " part from line, use "," as delimiter, then just add it as new Location(keep this, Words[0], Words[1], Words[2], Words[3])

Any suggestions to help solve this would be very appreciated!

Comment: `Split()` could be called with string array in parameters : `mystring.Split(new string[] {"=", ","};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] words = line.Split('=', ',');
```

Use that and you should be good. You were really close. You can actually add as many parameters as you want to `.split()` to include as many escape chars as needed. Just a tip though, if you're ever using 3 or more escape characters I'd suggest making an array of them first, then passing that array as the argument. keeps it clean!

Hope that helps bud!

Comment: Wow, can't believe I never knew you could do this.  Quick and simple.

Comment: Yeah for sure! If you're using Microsft Visual Studio, you can hover over these methods and a text popup will display more information on them. For me, hovering `.Split()` told me to pass this as an argument "params char[] separator". So I knew just from hovering over the function what to pass to it!

Comment: @Yahtzee Also, if you wouldn't mind marking this as answer for others to know this has been resolved that'd be great. Just click the arrow underneath the vote buttons to mark it as answer.

Comment: Just waiting on the 10 minute requirement to go by before marking an answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] Words = line.Split('=');
```

should possibly be:

```
string[] Words = words[1].Split(',');
```

*Since you have already split the line, the second item (index of 1) has everything to the right side of the `=`.*

Comment: This solution worked too but out of fairness going with the first answer posted.  Thanks though